# conda environment path in .bashrc

Tags: python, anaconda

I just uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda3 and It added this bloc in .bashrc file. Usually, it added only `export PATH="/home/***/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

```
# >>> conda init >>>
 # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
 __conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/home/****/anaconda3/bin/conda    ' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
 else
     if [ -f "/home/***/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
         . "/home/***/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
         CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
     else
         \export PATH="/home/***/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
     fi
 fi
 unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

What is the problem?

Comment: is this `CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base` two commands? if so, you're missing a `;` --> `CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false; conda activate base`

Comment: I run `CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base` without error. So what is the problem? I don't get your explanation

Comment: never mind.  i misread the question.

Comment: Is there actually a problem here? Are you experiencing an error or something? What is your question?

Comment: @darthbith everything seems good and I can create envs but I have a GPU problem. So I did not if it is coming from that or no

Comment: What GPU problem? You need to be specific in your question what your actual problem is (error messages, etc.) I don't think any GPU problems will be due to this init bit of conda, which is new since 4.4 (search for the conda 4.4 release notes), but you don't show any error messages, so I'm only guessing.

Comment: @darthbith `E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:353] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2018-10-09 12:12:04.477927: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:361] Possibly insufficient driver version: 390.48.0`

Comment: Please [edit] and put it in the question. And yes, this has nothing to do with conda. Why do you suspect conda is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

the "problem" is that conda added a block of code it never added before. The OP suspects conda because conda signed the code. This does **not** have "nothing to do with conda". It clearly has everything to do with conda.

Dear OP - Anaconda considers this to be an "improvement".

Comment: Funny improvement！ conda setting is the only and most ugly dirty in all my bashrc lines.